# Stretching video to fill div with MediaElement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

Is it possible?

I know it's a different thing all-together, but with jw media player you had the option to stretch the video to fill the div. It it just that html5 snubs it's nose at such things?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following

```
<div id="mediaContent">
                    <video id="mediaPlayer"  width="100%" height="100%">
                        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.debig_buck_bunny.mp4" /> 

                    </video>
                </div>
```

Then set your container div mediaContent in your CSS to be what ever size you want.
The video will then re-size to the container.
Strictly speaking the width and height should by absolute pixels dimensions, but setting to % works.

You may then have to set up the element with something like

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var myPlayer = $('#mediaPlayer');  

        var w = parseInt($('#mediaContent').css('width'));
        var h = parseInt($('#mediaContent').css('height')) ;

        myPlayer.mediaelementplayer({
            // if the <video width> is not specified, this is the default
            defaultVideoWidth: w ,
            // if the <video height> is not specified, this is the default
            defaultVideoHeight: h,
            // if set, overrides <video width>
            videoWidth: -1,
            // if set, overrides <video height>
            videoHeight: -1,
            // width of audio player
            audioWidth: 400,
            // height of audio player
            audioHeight: 30,
            // initial volume when the player starts
            startVolume: 0.8,
            // useful for <audio> player loops
            loop: false,
            // enables Flash and Silverlight to resize to content size
            enableAutosize: true,
            // the order of controls you want on the control bar (and other plugins below)
            features: ['playpause', 'progress', 'current', 'duration', 'tracks', 'volume', 'fullscreen'],
            // Hide controls when playing and mouse is not over the video
            alwaysShowControls: false,

            // forces the hour marker (##:00:00)
            alwaysShowHours: false,
            // show framecount in timecode (##:00:00:00)
            showTimecodeFrameCount: false,
            // used when showTimecodeFrameCount is set to true
            framesPerSecond: 25,
            // turns keyboard support on and off for this instance
            enableKeyboard: true,
            // when this player starts, it will pause other players
            pauseOtherPlayers: true,
            // array of keyboard commands
            keyActions: []

        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer above, the following one worked for me:

```
// Get video container width and height
var w = $('#video').parent().width();
var h = $('#video').parent().height();
$('#video')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .delay( 500 )  // don't know why, but without this sometimes it doesn't work.
    .mediaelementplayer({
        defaultVideoWidth: w
        , defaultVideoHeight: h
        , videoWidth: -1
        , videoHeight: -1
        , enableAutosize: true
    });
```